# O que está errado no meu array no php?

Tags: php, angularjs

Estou tentando montar um array, no php, que retornar para o meu controller, pois o retorno está exibindo no console 'undefined', por quê?

Controller

```
.controller('usuarioCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $window, $location) {

$scope.salvaUsuario = function (usuario) {
    var idCep = $window.localStorage.getItem('idCep');
    usuario.idCep = idCep;

       $http.post("http://localhost:8888/sistemas/webApps/ionic/vcApp/www/php/salvaUsuario.php", usuario).success(function (data){

        console.log(data);
        var ema = $window.localStorage.setItem("emailLogin", data.email);
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        if(data.cod === 1){
            $location.path('/cadastraUsuario');
            $scope.msgExiste = "Usuário já existente. Tente outro.";
        }

        });
        $location.path('/page10');
    }
})
```

PHP

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,X-Prototype-Version,X- Requested-With');

mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');

include_once("conPDO.php");

$pdo = conectar();

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data);

$nome = $data->nome;
$usuario = $data->usuario;
$email = $data->email;
$senha = $data->senha;
$idCep = $data->idCep;

$nome = utf8_decode($nome);
$tipoUsuario = "C";

$verificaUsuario=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome=:nome AND email=:email");
$verificaUsuario->bindValue("nome", $nome); 
$verificaUsuario->bindValue("email", $email); 
$verificaUsuario->execute();

$quant = $verificaUsuario->rowCount();

if($quant != 1){

    $result = array([
       'email' => $email
    ]);

    $insereUsuario=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (idUsuario, idCep, tipoUsuario, nome, usuario, email, senha) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $insereUsuario->bindValue(1, NULL); 
    $insereUsuario->bindValue(2, $idCep); 
    $insereUsuario->bindValue(3, $tipoUsuario); 
    $insereUsuario->bindValue(4, $nome);
    $insereUsuario->bindValue(5, $usuario);
    $insereUsuario->bindValue(6, $email);
    $insereUsuario->bindValue(7, $senha);

    $insereUsuario->execute();

    echo json_encode($result[0]);

}else{

    $result = array(
       'cod' => 1,
      );

    echo json_encode($result);

    return false;

}
```

Comment: tente usar sem as chaves $result = array(
       'email' => $email
    );

Comment: @RaphaelCaldas, o que apareceu no console, agora foi:
"<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset:  0 in <b>/home/vigil465/public_html/www/php/salvaUsuario.php</b> on line <b>52</b><br />
null"

Comment: Fiz uma resposta explicando amigão, boa sorte em seu projeto, de uma olhada lá, até mais ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigão testei aqui em meu site.

Cheguei a conclusão que você deveria usar `['CAMPO']`.

Sendo assim ficaria:

```
json_encode($result['email'])
```

Infelizmente não sei lhe informar o motivo do por que deve ser usado assim, mas irei dar um chute, aqui vai: como pode ser notado, seu array tem valores definidos como se fosse um Json(Exemplo de Comparação), então você deve puxar como se fosse com um Json, mas ai invés de usar `->` usar `['']`.

Espero que consiga arrumar em seu sistema, dê uma olhada em meu site que está com o link abaixo, lá eu mostro as etapas q eu usei para chegar a tal conclusão.

Boa sorte com seu projeto, qualquer coisa estou aqui para ajudar ;D

Como mostro aqui no meu site: http://netescola.info/stackover/

Comment: Entendi.
Consegui deixando só assim json_encode($result).
Valeu mesmo assim.

Answer (score 1):

Alguns problemas que vejo no seu código:

1 - Se é um json que você está retornando na resposta, o Header deve ser compatível. Ex: Ao invés de header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); usar header('Content-Type: **application/json**; charset=utf-8');

2 - Não há necessidade de usar:

```
$result = array([
   'email' => $email
]);
```

Para depois usar `echo json_encode($result[0]);` Você pode fazer direto `echo json_encode(array('email' => $email));`

3 - E no else quando você retornar um "cod=1", mas no angular você tenta acessar o data.email antes de comparar o cod, então se cair nesse else ele vai dar um erro de undefined porque o **data.email** não existe só existe o **data.cod**. Ou se ainda assim quiser retonar o email também, retorne echo `echo json_encode(array('cod' => 1 , 'email' => $email));`

4 - Aquele return false no fim está atoa alí :p

Comment: Oi @AndréKiffer
Com relação ao seu comentário de número 3, ele só retonará cod=1 caso ele caia na condição de usuário já existente.
Outra coisa que eu já havia notado é que se eu crio esse array, talvez não fosse necessário dar um echo json_encode($result[0]).
Valeu, você me ajudou a concluir isso kkkkkk